# MessageContract - invalid method generation

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, messagecontract

I have the following wcf service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUnitTestingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestsResult ExecuteUnitTests(UploadRequest unitTestsExecutionData);

}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.

public class TestResult
{
    public enum TestRunResult
    {
        Passed=1,
        Failed=2,
        Exception=3
    }

    public string TestName { get; set; }

    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    public string EndTime { get; set; }

    public string Result { get; set; }

}

[MessageContract(WrapperName = "TestResult"), DataContract]
public class TestsResult
{
   [MessageHeader, DataMember]
    public List<TestResult> Results { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader, DataMember]
   public int TotalExecutedTests { get; set; }

   [MessageHeader, DataMember]
    public int TotalPassedTests { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public int TotalFailedTests { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class UploadRequest
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public UnitTestingFrameworkType UnitTestingFrameworkType { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

However when i generate wcf client class via add service refference I get this:

```
 public UTS.ServiceReference1.TestResult[] ExecuteUnitTests(UTS.ServiceReference1.UnitTestingFrameworkType UnitTestingFrameworkType, System.IO.Stream Stream, out int TotalExecutedTests, out int TotalFailedTests, out int TotalPassedTests)
```

instead of this:

```
TestsResult ExecuteUnitTests(UploadRequest unitTestsExecutionData);
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this would cause this problem, but I would mark my similarly structured MessageContract up as follows:

1. Using the [MessageHeader] attribute is enough on MessageHeader members.
2. If the contract TestsResults is not a top level contract, I would mark it up as a DataContract with DataMember attributes only.

EDIT: 
3. TestResult should also be a DataContract, with all members marked up with DataMember.  Your enum must be marked up with the EnumMember attribute.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have solved my problem by making messageContract contain one complex type that contains all the required fields. That is allowed - i thought it's not

Comment: I am glad my comments helped you figure out the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am also faced same issue and solved it.

I've solved in two ways.

1. While adding Service Reference -> Check 'Always generate message contract' under DataType option
2. Add the following code in your client

    
   BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    
   ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory(myBinding, new EndpointAddress(""));
    
   IContractName client = factory.CreateChannel();

I hope this helps.